# Getting input with the speech recognition (speechRecognized)

Tags: c#, if-statement, speech-recognition

I want to have code like this:

```
Edi.speak ("would you like more information")

 bool accepted  = speechrecognized

If (speechrecognized = yes)
{
}

else
{
}
```

I know this is wrong but I want the user to say yes through the microphone and the statement is carried out when yes, but if the user says no it carries out the statement. How do I get the yes and no through to the if statement using speech recognition?
please forgive for lack of better way to explain my situation.
Thanks

Comment: Use a speech library and try at your end. Then post here if you face issues.

Comment: Which one please. I am in high school ,15 and I don't really have much experience although I have been programming since I was 12.

Comment: You can study documentation on System.Speech API here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378426(v=office.14).aspx